# type error a bytes-like object or a > number, not 'Image' when i try to use np.expand_dim()

Tags: python, numpy, keras

```
  image_path_dir = 'C:\\Python'
  images_paths = [join(image_path_dir, imagename) for imagename in ['sna3.jpg', 'sna1.jpg', 'bag5.jpg', 't2.jpg', 's3.jpg',
                                                                 'sn2.jpg', 't2.jpg']]



def img_pre_pro(img, img_width=28, img_height=28):

    imgs = [load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height)) for image_path in images_paths]

    for imga in imgs:

        imgs = np.expand_dims(imgs, axis = 2)
    imgs_array = np.array([img_to_array(imgss)/255 for imgss in imgs])
    return imgs_array

new_img = img_pre_pro('images_paths')
```

when i remove the expand_dim statement from the function it works well, but i have to change the 'rgb'dimension 
of the image to 1, it is pretty striaght forword when doing it with just one image.. i get the below error when i try

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-54-bb26feed97ab> in <module>
>      15     return imgs_array
>      16 
> ---> 17 new_img = img_pre_pro('images_paths')
>      18 
> 
> <ipython-input-54-bb26feed97ab> in img_pre_pro(img, img_width,
> img_height)
>      11     for imga in imgs:
>      12 
> ---> 13         imgs = np.expand_dims(imgs, axis = 2)
>      14     imgs_array = np.array([img_to_array(imgss)/255 for imgss in imgs])
>      15     return imgs_array
> 
> <__array_function__ internals> in expand_dims(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> c:\users\allaye\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py
> in expand_dims(a, axis)
>     589         a = asarray(a)
>     590     else:
> --> 591         a = asanyarray(a)
>     592 
>     593     if type(axis) not in (tuple, list):
> 
> c:\users\allaye\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py
> in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
>     136 
>     137     """
> --> 138     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
>     139 
>     140 
> 
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'Image'
```

Comment: I think you need to look at your load_img function, could it be returning a PIL Image?  If so you need to convert it to a numpy array, before expanding it's dimensions.

Comment: Why pass `imgs` to expand? Thats a list.  `imga` is the iteration variable.

Comment: @hpaulj i have corrected that though, but still gets the same error

Comment: @ColinDickie have done that also but still

Comment: What have you done?  How did you convert the `Image` to array?

Comment: `expend_dims` will work on an list of arrays; you don't need to iterate on the list your self.  Still,  it needs to be a list of arrays, not a list of `pil.image` objects.

Comment: @hpaulj   okay i did that but i got a 5D tensor instead of 4D tensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you never read the docstring of the load_img, it accepts an argument to convert 
color images into grayscale, if that is what you want, using your own code I just added the color_mode argument.

```
def img_pre_pro_keras(img, img_width=28, img_height=28, normalization = None):

    imgs = [load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height),color_mode='grayscale') for image_path in images_paths]

    imgs_array = np.array([img_to_array(imgss)/255 for imgss in imgs])

    return imgs_array
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def img_pre_pro(img, img_width=28, img_height=28):

    imgs = [load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height)) for image_path in images_paths]



    imgs_array = np.array([img_to_array(imgss)/255 for imgss in imgs])
    imgs_array = np.expand_dims(imgs_array, axis = 3)

    return imgs_array

new_img = img_pre_pro(img)
new_img.shape

result is (7, 28, 28, 1, 3)
```

the array is supposed to be a 4D tensor not five and i cant use np.squeeze()

Comment: What if you don't use `expand_dims` at all?  That's what's adding the size 1 dimension.  What was the purpose in the first place?  Or, what shape do you need?

Comment: the dimension of the image is (28,28,3) now am having 7 images and i want to convert the last color channel from 3 to 1 after everything i want to get this (7,28,28,1) as my shape

Comment: Do you understand the significance of that size 3 dimension?

Comment: yeah, that is the color channel, and i want to make it gray scale

Comment: read the  doc_string of the function 'load_img' your solution is there..

Comment: @Allaye i have done that but i cant get it to work, please any help